# cljsjs/react-beautiful-dnd onDragEnd handler not firing in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, reagent

I'm pretty new, so apologies for any oversight on format here. I've exhausted other sources:

Any insight on why an onDragEnd handler won't work in Chrome but will in Safari?

Thanks

edit:

Sorry about that. Won't work as in: I've got an :onDragEnd function established. As a means to test, the handler function just triggers a js/alert to pop up. I also tried to print to the console to confirm it was working as well. In both cases, the onDragEnd handler triggered as expected when done in Safari, but Chrome doesn't seem to recognize the onDragEnd event or something.

```
(defn abc []
 [DragDropContext
   {:onDragEnd on-drag-end-handler}
     [Droppable...
       [Draggable...
          somestuff]]])

(defn on-drag-end-handler []
  (js/alert "FOO"))
```

Comment: Please define "wont work" and add the code/the minimal failing example you see that error